# Insert Geocoding In Joomla Component Backend 2.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm currently developing my first component for Joomla 2.5, Ive inserted jForm in the backend, I now need to add java script in the back-end, for i need to geo-code an inserted address and then fill in two fields one being latitude and the other longitude.

everytime i try to insert any form of script in the back-end i get a 500 error.

Any Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the code you're using to insert the javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as simple as:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false");
$document->addScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js");
$document->addScript(JURI::base() . 'media/mod_locate/js/mod_map.js');
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base() . 'media/mod_locate/css/mod_map.css');
```

Thanks anyway :)